# Give charging from one android phone to another via usb

Tags: android, usb

My idea is to charge one android phone from another android phone using usb. 
Both phones should be directly connected via micro-usb wire. Is this possible? Is it possible to create an app which controls this kind of charging? Please help me with this. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

You most likely could charge one device from the other as long as the device you're charging from has USB OTG (On-The-Go) support. You'd need the correct type of cable (usually called a 'host cable'), then into that you'd plug your usual charger cable for the device to be charged.

Some devices may not provide enough power from their USB OTG port so your mileage may vary there. Don't be surprised if it works but *very* slowly.

As for creating an app to control it I'm almost 100% sure that's a no - I don't believe whether or not power is supplied to a USB port is switchable.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

As jackjames said, you can use USB OTG. That way you can charge the one in device mode using the one in host mode. First you need to make sure that the power supplying device supports USB host mode. There are various free apps to test that. (OTG Troubshooter for example). Then you need an OTG cable. Just connect the devices and voila!
It might be slow, but I don't think you can create an app to control it.

Comment: How to set device in host mode ? Is there any setting ?